# Not finding the exact field in JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that is scrape from the crunchbase and wanted to print 'contact_field' from the file

this is sample of the contact field in JSON file look like.

```
"contact_fields": {
              "contact_email": "info@email.com",
              "phone_number": "+44 800 011 9688"
            },
```

the code below is To find the contact field to print the contact info and the phone number

```
with open('html_found.json') as filter:
    data = json.load(filter)

# Find and print the specified content if it exists
if "contact_fields" in data:
    contact_fields = data["contact_fields"]
    contact_email = contact_fields.get("contact_email")
    phone_number = contact_fields.get("phone_number")

    if contact_email:
        print("Contact Email:", contact_email)
    else:
        print("Contact Email not found.")

    if phone_number:
        print("Phone Number:", phone_number)
    else:
        print("Phone Number not found.")
else:
    print("No contact fields found in the JSON data.")
```

The output says "No contact fields found in the json" even tho its in the file. Did i make any mistake in the file or on the line

Below is the lines from html_found.json using the json beautify

[image]

Comment: Did you try `print`ing `data` to see if it is there?

Comment: Agree, because your code works fine. Try to print `data` and paste in the question. Or paste the minimal producible example of `html_found.json` in the question

Comment: @Selcuk after i print data it shows everything

Comment: @Ybanks I believe you are mistaken.

Comment: @Selcuk 

in the actual html.json file. On line 2059 is what it look like

        **"contact_fields": {
              "contact_email": "info@evaluagent.com",
              "phone_number": "+44 800 011 9688"
            },
            "social_fields": {
              "facebook": {
                "value": "https://www.facebook.com/evaluagent"
              },
              "linkedin": {
                "value": "http://www.linkedin.com/company/evaluagent"
              },**

Comment: Posting line 2059 doesn't help much. There may be a zillion nested keys before it. Your code requires `contact_fields` to be a root key, which is not obvious from the snippet you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in general works. I added a small write before that writes exactly what you have posted into a json and then reads and parses it. Are you sure the `contact_fields` is not itself inside a list or another dict, so it can be accessed directly via `data["contract_fields"]`? Please provide a full json which reproduces your problem, with the part you have posted nothing is wrong at the moment.

```py
import json

with open('tmp.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write('{"contact_fields": {"contact_email": "info@email.com","phone_number": "+44 800 011 9688"}}')

with open('tmp.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Find and print the specified content if it exists
if "contact_fields" in data:
    contact_fields = data["contact_fields"]
    contact_email = contact_fields.get("contact_email")
    phone_number = contact_fields.get("phone_number")

    if contact_email:
        print("Contact Email:", contact_email)
    else:
        print("Contact Email not found.")

    if phone_number:
        print("Phone Number:", phone_number)
    else:
        print("Phone Number not found.")
else:
    print("No contact fields found in the JSON data.")
```

My output

```
Contact Email: info@email.com
Phone Number: +44 800 011 9688
```

EDIT:
Based on the newly added screenshot of the json it is clear that `contact_fields` is not at the root level of the json. I am going to assume what is posted is now the json which you want to parse.

So the way to get to contact_fields is something like

```py
data['HttpState']['GET/v4/data/...']['data']['cards']['contact_fields']
```

Note that I did not type the whole key for `GET/v4/data/...` it is quite long, so you need to replace it by the full string.

Also no idea how static this whole json is, especially the key under `HttpState` seems like it might change. So hard coding the access might break.

Comment: i have posted the line of what it look like in the html_found.json file

Comment: This is still not enough I am afraid. The code will still work with that if I assume the json content is just surrounded by `{}`, so that the `"contact_fields"` is on the root level.  So what I assume is the case is that `"contact_fields"` is somewhere down the tree structure of the json and not on the first level, so you can't do `data["contact_fields"]` and it might has to be `data["some_key"]["contact_fields"]`. Try to trim down the json but keep all the different levels of it. Or maybe just post the whole thing.

Comment: i have posted the screenshot of the json beautify where contact_field can be found. on the left is the json. then on the right is the tree of where is the contact_field

Comment: Screenshots are hard to read and can't be searched. They should be avoided whenever possible. However, in this case the screenshot shows the data you want it deeply nested in the JSON structure. So unless your *tmp.json* file only contains the data rooted at the `cards` node your code won't find it.

Comment: @Ybanks I did update my answer based on the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The json module converts a Json file or string into a hierachy of lists and dicts. But the `in` Python operator only research for a key in a simple dict. More generally, Python offers no direct way to recursively search into a complex hierarchy, but it is rather simple do write a function for it:

```
def search(data, key: str):
    """Recursively search key in an arbitrary json data"""
    def _do_search(data, key):
        """Apply search over an iterable sequence"""
        for d in data:
            newd = search(d, key)
            if newd is not None:
                return newd
        return None
    # is it a list?
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return _do_search(data, key)
    # or a dict?
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        if key in data:  # we found the key: just return it
            return data[key]
        return _do_search(data.values(), key) # else recurse
    return None
```

Your code could become

```
with open('html_found.json') as filter:
    data = json.load(filter)

    # Find and print the specified content if it exists
    contact_fields = search(data, "contact_fields")
    if "contact_fields" is not None:
        contact_email = contact_fields.get("contact_email")
        phone_number = contact_fields.get("phone_number")
    
        if contact_email:
            print("Contact Email:", contact_email)
        else:
            print("Contact Email not found.")
    
        if phone_number:
            print("Phone Number:", phone_number)
        else:
            print("Phone Number not found.")
    else:
        print("No contact fields found in the JSON data.")
```